# Complete list of XHTML, MathML, and SVG modules and other entities, with public identifiers?

Tags: svg, xhtml, mathml

The XHTML 1.1 modular specification https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd references various modules which, in turn, reference other entities, in all pulling in entity reference definitions, DTDs, etc.

In addition other DTDs such as https://www.w3.org/2002/04/xhtml-math-svg/xhtml-math-svg.dtd pull in all sorts of MathML and SVG entities, which in turn reference other entities.

Is there some place that simply lists all the XHTML/MathML/SVG entities by public ID (e.g. `-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Base Architecture 1.0//EN`), along with a good place to download them (e.g. https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-arch-1.mod )? I'm accumulating quite a list myself, but recursively poring over the DTDs is time-consuming and error-prone (not to mention monotonous and as boring as heck).

Answer (score 1):

The list of entities shipped with Saxon has no official standing, but feel free to use it:

https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.9/hej/net/sf/saxon/lib/StandardEntityResolver.java

The first argument is a public ID, the second is the URI at W3C, the third is the location within the Saxon JAR file.

There are a number of errors in the published documents, e.g. where one file refers to another using an incorrect public ID.

```
        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES Latin 1 for XHTML//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent",
                "w3c/xhtml-lat1.ent");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES Symbols for XHTML//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-symbol.ent",
                "w3c/xhtml-symbol.ent");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES Special for XHTML//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-special.ent",
                "w3c/xhtml-special.ent");

        register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd",
                "w3c/xhtml10/xhtml1-transitional.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd",
                "w3c/xhtml10/xhtml1-strict.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd",
                "w3c/xhtml10/xhtml1-frameset.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic10.dtd",
                "w3c/xhtml10/xhtml-basic10.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml11.dtd",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml11.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.1//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-basic11.dtd",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-basic11.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Access Element 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-access-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-access-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Access Attribute Qnames 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-access-qname-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-access-qname-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Java Applets 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-applet-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-applet-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Base Architecture 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-arch-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-arch-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Common Attributes 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-attribs-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-attribs-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Base Element 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-base-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-base-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Basic Forms 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-basic-form-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-basic-form-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Basic Tables 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-basic-table-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-basic-table-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Basic 1.0 Document Model 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-basic10-model-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-basic10-model-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Basic 1.1 Document Model 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-basic11-model-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-basic11-model-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML BDO Element 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-bdo-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-bdo-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML BIDI Override Element 1.0//EN", //should be "BDO Element 1.0" not "BIDI Override Element 1.0"
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-bdo-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-bdo-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Block Phrasal 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-blkphras-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-blkphras-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Block Presentation 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-blkpres-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-blkpres-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Block Structural 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-blkstruct-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-blkstruct-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Character Entities 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-charent-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-charent-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Client-side Image Maps 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-csismap-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-csismap-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Datatypes 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-datatypes-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-datatypes-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Editing Markup 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-edit-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-edit-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Editing Elements 1.0//EN",   // should be "Editing Markup" not "Editing Elements", but allow both
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-edit-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-edit-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Intrinsic Events 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-events-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-events-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Forms 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-form-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-form-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Frames 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-frames-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-frames-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Modular Framework 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-framework-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-framework-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML HyperAttributes 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-hyperAttributes-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-hyperAttributes-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Hypertext 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-hypertext-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-hypertext-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Frame Element 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-iframe-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-iframe-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Images 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-image-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-image-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Phrasal 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlphras-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-inlphras-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Presentation 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlpres-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-inlpres-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Structural 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlstruct-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-inlstruct-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Inline Style 1.0//EN",  // should be "ELEMENTS" not "ENTITIES", but allow either
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Style 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inputmode 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inputmode-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-inputmode-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Legacy Markup 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-legacy-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-legacy-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Legacy Redeclarations 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-legacy-redecl-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-legacy-redecl-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Link Element 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-link-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-link-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Lists 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-list-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-list-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Metainformation 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-meta-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-meta-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Metainformation 2.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-meta-2.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-meta-2.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML MetaAttributes 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-metaAttributes-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-metaAttributes-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Name Identifier 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-nameident-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-nameident-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//NOTATIONS XHTML Notations 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-notations-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-notations-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Embedded Object 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-object-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-object-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Param Element 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-param-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-param-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Presentation 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-pres-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-pres-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML-Print 1.0 Document Model 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-print10-model-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-print10-model-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Qualified Names 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-qname-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-qname-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML+RDFa Document Model 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-model-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-rdfa-model-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML RDFa Attribute Qnames 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-qname-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-rdfa-qname-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Role Attribute 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-role-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-role-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Role Attribute Qnames 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-role-qname-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-role-qname-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Ruby 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/ruby/xhtml-ruby-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-ruby-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Scripting 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-script-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-script-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Server-side Image Maps 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-ssismap-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-ssismap-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Document Structure 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-struct-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-struct-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//DTD XHTML Style Sheets 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-style-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-style-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Style Sheets 1.0//EN",  // should be "DTD XHTML" not "ELEMENTS XHTML"
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-style-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-style-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Tables 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-table-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-table-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Target 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-target-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-target-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Text 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-text-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml-text-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML 1.1 Document Model 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml11-model-1.mod",
                "w3c/xhtml11/xhtml11-model-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//MathML 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml1/mathml.dtd",
                "w3c/mathml/mathml1/mathml.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD MathML 2.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/mathml2.dtd",
                "w3c/mathml/mathml2/mathml2.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD MathML 3.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml3/mathml3.dtd",
                "w3c/mathml/mathml3/mathml3.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd",
                "w3c/svg10/svg10.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd",
                "w3c/svg11/svg11.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1 Tiny//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-tiny.dtd",
                "w3c/svg11/svg11-tiny.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1 Basic//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-basic.dtd",
                "w3c/svg11/svg11-basic.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Document Model//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-model.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg11-model.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Attribute Collection//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-attribs.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg11-attribs.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Modular Framework//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-framework.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-framework.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Datatypes//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-datatypes.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-datatypes.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Qualified Name//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-qname.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-qname.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Core Attribute//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-core-attrib.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-core-attrib.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Container Attribute//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-container-attrib.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-container-attrib.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Viewport Attribute//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-viewport-attrib.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-viewport-attrib.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Paint Attribute//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-paint-attrib.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-paint-attrib.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Paint Opacity Attribute//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-opacity-attrib.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-opacity-attrib.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Graphics Attribute//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-graphics-attrib.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-graphics-attrib.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Document Events Attribute//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-docevents-attrib.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-docevents-attrib.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Graphical Element Events Attribute//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-graphevents-attrib.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-graphevents-attrib.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 Animation Events Attribute//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-animevents-attrib.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-animevents-attrib.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 XLink Attribute//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-xlink-attrib.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-xlink-attrib.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ENTITIES SVG 1.1 External Resources Attribute//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-extresources-attrib.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-extresources-attrib.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Structure//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-structure.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-structure.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Conditional Processing//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-conditional.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-conditional.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Image//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-image.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-image.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Style//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-style.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-style.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Shape//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-shape.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-shape.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Text//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-text.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-text.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Marker//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-marker.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-marker.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Color Profile//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-profile.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-profile.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Gradient//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-gradient.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-gradient.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Pattern//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-pattern.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-pattern.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Clip//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-clip.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-clip.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Mask//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-mask.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-mask.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Filter//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-filter.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-filter.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Cursor//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-cursor.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-cursor.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Hyperlinking//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-hyperlink.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-hyperlink.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 View//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-view.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-view.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Scripting//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-script.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-script.mod");


        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Animation//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-animation.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-animation.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Font//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-font.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-font.mod");

        register("-//W3C//ELEMENTS SVG 1.1 Extensibility//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg-extensibility.mod",
                "w3c/svg11/svg-extensibility.mod");

        register("-//XML-DEV//ENTITIES RDDL Document Model 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.rddl.org/xhtml-rddl-model-1.mod",
                "w3c/rddl/xhtml-rddl-model-1.mod");

        register("-//XML-DEV//DTD XHTML RDDL 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.rddl.org/rddl-xhtml.dtd",
                "w3c/rddl/rddl-xhtml.dtd");

        register("-//XML-DEV//ENTITIES RDDL QName Module 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.rddl.org/rddl-qname-1.mod",
                "w3c/rddl/rddl-qname-1.mod");

        register("-//XML-DEV//ENTITIES RDDL Resource Module 1.0//EN",
                "http://www.rddl.org/rddl-resource-1.mod",
                "w3c/rddl/rddl-resource-1.mod");

        register("-//XML-DEV//ELEMENTS RDDL Resource 1.0//EN",
                 "http://www.rddl.org/rddl-resource-1.mod",
                 "w3c/rddl/rddl-resource-1.mod");

        register("-//XML-DEV//ENTITIES XLink Module 1.0//EN",
                 "http://www.rddl.org/rddl-resource-1.mod",
                 "w3c/rddl/xlink-module-1.mod");

        register("-//W3C//DTD Specification V2.10//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/2002/xmlspec/dtd/2.10/xmlspec.dtd",
                "w3c/xmlspec/xmlspec.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD XMLSCHEMA 200102//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd",
                "w3c/xmlschema10/XMLSchema.dtd");

        register("datatypes",
                "http://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd",
                "w3c/xmlschema10/datatypes.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD XSD 1.1//EN",
                 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/XMLSchema.dtd",
                 "w3c/xmlschema11/XMLSchema.dtd");

        register("-//W3C//DTD XSD 1.1 Datatypes//EN",
                 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/datatypes.dtd",
                 "w3c/xmlschema11/datatypes.dtd");

        register("xpath-functions",
                "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions.xsd",
                "xpath-functions.xsd");

        register("json",
                 "http://www.w3.org/2005/json.xsd",
                 "xpath-functions.xsd");

        register("analyze-string",
                 "http://www.w3.org/2005/analyze-string.xsd",
                 "xpath-functions.xsd");

        register("xml-to-json",
                "xml-to-json.xsl",
                "xml-to-json.xsl");

        register("xml-to-json-indent",
                "xml-to-json-indent.xsl",
                "xml-to-json-indent.xsl");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's an honor to receive a reply from you. I have your _XSLT Programmer's Reference, Second Edition_ from Wrox, which I scanned in at 600dpi and OCRed back in 2004 for lack of an ebook. (I was one of the DTD editors for OEBPS, which became EPUB, back in 1999.) Back to to the subject at hand, you mention there are errors in the published documents; perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/60568097/421049 is one of them. Anyway thanks for the list of entities. Some day I'll compare them to the ones I culled by hand as part of https://globalmentor.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-175 .