# Java XML parser adding unnecessary xmlns and xml:space attributes

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces, dtd

I'm using Java 11 (AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.5 2019-10-15) on Windows 10. I'm parsing some legacy XHTML 1.1 files, which take the following general form:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <title>XHTML 1.1 Skeleton</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using a simple non-validating parser:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
final Document document;
try (InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("xhtml-1.1-test.xhtml"))) {
  document = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
}
```

For some reason it's adding extra attributes such as `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` and `xml:space="preserve"` all over the place:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xml:lang="en">
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <title xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">XHTML 1.1 Skeleton</title>
</head>
<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xml:space="preserve"></body>
</html>
```

I know that DTDs can provide default attribute values, but I don't understand why the `xmlns:xsi` attribute was added, when there appear to be no elements or attributes in that namespace.

Furthermore `xml:space="preserve"` seems to be incorrect altogether; only elements like `<pre>` should have `xml:space="preserve"` set, I would think. (*Update:* The [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#global-attributes) indicates that HTML by default preserves space, and that `xml:space` must not be serialized in HTML, so maybe that was part of the reasoning here. I will improve my HTML serializer to ignore the `xml:space` attribute, which will partially mitigate this issue.)

Also note the `version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"` as well; that's something I don't need or want.

**Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way I can configure the parser not to include this unnecessary cruft?**

Interestingly this is not a problem with XHTML 1.0 strict.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>XHTML 1.0 Skeleton</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When parsed that yields what one would expect:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>XHTML 1.0 Skeleton</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But it is a problem with `-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0 plus SVG 1.1//EN`. So this seems to be just an XHTML 1.1 problem.

*Update:* I have some potentially helpful news: if I create a new document without a DTD and import the entire document tree into the new document, all this cruft (which apparently comes from implied attributes in the DTD) goes away, because the destination document doesn't have a DTD at all. (See [How to force removal of attributes with implied default values from DTD in Java XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60688446/421049) .) But this is very inefficient; it would be nice to turn this off altogether when parsing.

Comment: What is `DefaultEntityResolver`? Also, regarding "For some reason it's adding extra attributes", do you mean that it is added to the original xml file? If not, how do you convert the `Document` object to XML string (or saving it to a file)?

Comment: `DefaultEntityResolver` is an entity resolver that supplies the entities (such as DTDs) locally instead of downloading them from the Internet. See the ticket https://globalmentor.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-175 , or clone commit https://bitbucket.org/globalmentor/%7B15a9ee2f-e9fa-4dd1-8185-9ef4e2f6c713%7D/commits/4f74e003fa6c91600ab11fc379ea1712b86ab415 if you want to verify the contents of the entities.

Comment: When I say, "for some reason it's adding extra attributes", I mean that it's adding them to the DOM tree. I'm using a custom XML serializer I wrote myself to print out the tree.

Comment: What happens if you remove the DefaultEntityResolver?

Comment: If I remove the `DefaultEntityResolver`, then it won't even parse, and crashes because of a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` for `http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml-datatypes-1.mod`. Apparently the W3C has removed this entity from its website altogether. (So does no one parse XHTML 1.1 files anymore with standard Java XML parsers? This is completely broken.) So I must use a custom entity resolver with locally stored entities or it won't even parse. @Olivier have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Note that if I use `http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml11.dtd` for the DTD system ID, it parses successfully even without using the `DefaultEntityResolver` (although it takes about 10 minutes on my system to access the DTDs). Unfortunately the same result occurs. I'll update the question to use this working URL, and remove the `DefaultEntityResolver`. And I've created https://stackoverflow.com/q/60655704/421049 about the missing entity at the other URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround, although it's not ideal. The idea is that when a document asks to be parsed with the XHTML 1.1 DTD `-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN`, to really use the XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD `-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN` instead. For most practical purposes this DTD is [effectively almost the same](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/changes.html) as the one they asked for, but it doesn't bring in all the default cruft.

Remembering that `DefaultEntityResolver` is my entity resolver with most of the XHTML DTDs predefined (see [Complete list of XHTML, MathML, and SVG modules and other entities, with public identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60568284/421049)), the implementation looks something like this:

```java
private static final EntityResolver XHTML_1_1_TO_XHTML_1_0_ENTITY_RESOLVER =
    new EntityResolver() {

  private final EntityResolver defaultEntityResolver = DefaultEntityResolver.getInstance();

  @Override
  public InputSource resolveEntity(final String publicID, final String systemID)
      throws SAXException, IOException {
    if(XHTML_1_1_PUBLIC_ID.equals(publicID)) {
      final InputSource inputSource = resolveEntity(XHTML_1_0_STRICT_PUBLIC_ID, systemID);
      inputSource.setPublicId(publicID);
      return inputSource;
    }
    return defaultEntityResolver.resolveEntity(publicID, systemID);
  }

};
```

Then I would use that entity resolver when parsing:

```java
documentBuilder.setEntityResolver(XHTML_1_1_TO_XHTML_1_0_ENTITY_RESOLVER);
```

It's somewhat of a kludge, and semantically I don't like it. But for my application I just need a clean, well-formed parsed document with correct entity replacement, so in practice it may produce effectively the same results for most documents.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar` Xerces configuration feature?

However, I've just been looking at how I do this in Saxon, and I don't ask the XML parser to not-report defaulted attributes, rather I discard them when they are reported. I'm using Xerces as a SAX parser not a DOM parser though. (In SAX, defaulted attributes are reported using `Attributes2.isDefaulted()`).

Comment: "Have you tried the `nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar` Xerces configuration feature?" No, I've never heard of it. Is it guaranteed to be supported by the built-in Java 11 XML parser? I frankly haven't kept up with the state of Java XML parsing in the past few years. I wrote an entire XML parser from scratch in 1999 because the existing Java parser was so slow; some time around then Java integrated the W3C DOM API into the standard library. When that happened I transitioned over from my parser to the Java one, but otherwise I haven't kept up with the latest developments.

Comment: The features supported by Apache Xerces seem to be much better documented than the features supported by the JDK version. I still use Apache Xerces out of habit because for years it was much more reliable than the JDK version, but that justification seems to have disappeared these days.

Comment: Interestingly today I found out that [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#global-attributes) says that `xml:space` shouldn't even be serialized in HTML, so I'll update my HTML serializer to ignore `xml:space`; that will partially mitigate this. Meanwhile I'll still use my workaround until I update my HTML serializer to remove redundant namespace declarations and figure out how to elegantly get rid of the XHTML `version` attribute.