# How to force removal of attributes with implied default values from DTD in Java XML DOM

Tags: java, xml, dtd, xmldom

As I reported [elsewhere on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60603441/421049), I'm parsing a legacy modular XHTML 1.1 document and the DTD is adding all sorts of default attributes such as `version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"`. Some of these are even inappropriate, such as `xml:space="preserve"`.

I'm writing a utility to clean up the DOM after parsing, but I forgot that the DOM will automatically add back default attributes from the DTD if I remove them. So if I call `Element.removeAttributeNS(null, "version")` on the document element, for example, it just adds back `version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"` and I'm back where I started.

How can I force the DOM in Java to remove an attribute, even if the DTD indicates that attribute has an implied value? Or how can I just change/remove the DTD from the DOM tree so that implied attributes don't automatically show up?

I have succeeded in created a new, empty document without a DTD; importing the old document element and its descendants; and then replacing the root element in the new document with the imported element tree, but this is a lot of overhead and too inefficient. Is there a more efficient workaround or solution?

Comment: Can't you just parse without validation?

Comment: But I am parsing without validation! See code at https://stackoverflow.com/q/60603441/421049 . (Validation is turned off by default.) Whether default values appear in the DOM from the DTD doesn't seem to be related to validation. After all the parser must parse and use the DTD even if validation is turned off (e.g. to discover an `&mdash;` entity); otherwise, the document might not be well-formed.