# W3C breaks XHTML 1.1 parsing by removing modules from web site

Tags: java, xml, dtd

The W3C [recommended list of doctype declarations](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) indicates the following doctype for XHTML 1.1:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

This is the same system ID recommended by [A List Apart](https://alistapart.com/article/doctype/), the [Wiley Dummies site](https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/site-development/an-introduction-to-doctypes-dtds/), among many others. It was one of the standard system ID for the modular XHTML 1.1 DTD.

Unfortunately this modular DTD refers to other XML entities, some of which the W3C has removed from its site, completely breaking parsing.

You can test this in Java 11. Start with the following XHTML 1.1 file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <title>XHTML 1.1 Skeleton</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Try to parse it using a standard, built-in Java parser:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
final Document document;
try (InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("xhtml-1.1-test.xhtml"))) {
  document = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
}
```

Parsing will fail, throwing a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` for `http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml-datatypes-1.mod`. Apparently the W3C has removed this entity from its web site altogether.

If instead `http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml11.dtd` is used (which appears a a comment in the [XHTML 1.1 specification DTD](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/xhtml11_dtd.html)), parsing completes normally (albeit after about 10 minutes).

Why does the W3C make insufficient entities available at the `http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/` collection, breaking XHTML 1.1 parsing with a standard system ID? Why aren't all the modules available that are available at `http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/`? Who at the W3C should I contact to get this fixed? (And why does HTTP access take so long for these entities?)

Comment: Would you consider calling [DocumentBuilder.setEntityResolver](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#setEntityResolver%28org.xml.sax.EntityResolver%29) an acceptable workaround?

Comment: I'm not asking for a workaround. I already have a workaround with my own entity resolver; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/60568284/421049 . I'm trying to say that the W3C has broken the entire XHTML 1.1 parsing infrastructure that has been in place for around two decades. The W3C needs to put the appropriate entity resources back online, and they need to be served more quickly. Otherwise they are breaking supposedly standards-compliant data. How can we report this to the W3C and get resolution of this problem?

Comment: Perhaps https://lists.whatwg.org?

Comment: That sounded good for a minute, until I read on the page: "The WHATWG mailing lists are no longer active."

Comment: Besides, isn't this a W3C issue? Isn't the W3C still a completely separate entity than WHATWG?

Comment: I admit I don’t know the relationship between the two.  But the second sentence on that page (“Discussions now happen…”) contains two links to what what it suggests are still active lists (and an active github issue repository).

Comment: Yeah, WHATWG is a completely separate entity. They weren't around when the W3C created modularized XHTML 1.1. In fact the creation of the WHATWG ironically was largely in response to the long time the W3C was taking in its creating a new XHTML. You can read more [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHATWG). So I imagine the WHATWG doesn't care much of the W3C isn't maintaining its old specifications the WHATWG didn't like to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you mentioned as alternative - `http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml11.dtd` - seems to be consistently used in the XHTML 1.1 specs/DTDs/modules and appears to be the one endorsed by W3C, rather than `http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd`. My guess is access to these declaration sets is deliberately throttled, as W3C doesn't want to serve these to the general public; you're supposed to store these locally and use an SGML/XML catalog file mapping identifiers to your local entity/declaration sets.

I had success in validating an XHTML 1.1 file using libxml2's `xmllint` command-line tool by invoking

```
 SGML_CATALOG_FILES=./catalog xmllint --catalogs --dtdvalid xhtml11.dtd testdoc.xhtml
```

with a `catalog` file having the following content (and the referenced `.dtd`, `.mod` and `.ent` files in place in that directory, of course):

```
OVERRIDE YES

SGMLDECL "xml1.dcl"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "xhtml11.dtd"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML 1.1 Document Model 1.0//EN" "xhtml11-model-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Common Attributes 1.0//EN" "xhtml-attribs-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-attribs-1.mod" "xhtml-attribs-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Base Element 1.0//EN" "xhtml-base-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-base-1.mod" "xhtml-base-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML BDO Element 1.0//EN" "xhtml-bdo-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-bdo-1.mod" "xhtml-bdo-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Block Phrasal 1.0//EN" "xhtml-blkphras-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-blkphras-1.mod" "xhtml-blkphras-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Block Presentation 1.0//EN" "xhtml-blkpres-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-blkpres-1.mod" "xhtml-blkpres-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Block Structural 1.0//EN" "xhtml-blkstruct-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-blkstruct-1.mod" "xhtml-blkstruct-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Character Entities 1.0//EN" "xhtml-charent-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-charent-1.mod" "xhtml-charent-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Client-side Image Maps 1.0//EN" "xhtml-csismap-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-csismap-1.mod" "xhtml-csismap-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Datatypes 1.0//EN" "xhtml-datatypes-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-datatypes-1.mod" "xhtml-datatypes-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Editing Markup 1.0//EN" "xhtml-edit-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-edit-1.mod" "xhtml-edit-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Intrinsic Events 1.0//EN" "xhtml-events-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-events-1.mod" "xhtml-events-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Forms 1.0//EN" "xhtml-form-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-form-1.mod" "xhtml-form-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Modular Framework 1.0//EN" "xhtml-framework-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-framework-1.mod" "xhtml-framework-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Hypertext 1.0//EN" "xhtml-hypertext-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-hypertext-1.mod" "xhtml-hypertext-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Images 1.0//EN" "xhtml-image-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-image-1.mod" "xhtml-image-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Phrasal 1.0//EN" "xhtml-inlphras-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlphras-1.mod" "xhtml-inlphras-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Presentation 1.0//EN" "xhtml-inlpres-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlpres-1.mod" "xhtml-inlpres-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Inline Structural 1.0//EN" "xhtml-inlstruct-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlstruct-1.mod" "xhtml-inlstruct-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Inline Style 1.0//EN" "xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod" "xhtml-inlstyle-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Legacy Markup 1.0//EN" "xhtml-legacy-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-legacy-1.mod" "xhtml-legacy-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Link Element 1.0//EN" "xhtml-link-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-link-1.mod" "xhtml-link-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Lists 1.0//EN" "xhtml-list-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-list-1.mod" "xhtml-list-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Metainformation 1.0//EN" "xhtml-meta-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-meta-1.mod" "xhtml-meta-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Embedded Object 1.0//EN" "xhtml-object-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-object-1.mod" "xhtml-object-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Param Element 1.0//EN" "xhtml-param-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-param-1.mod" "xhtml-param-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Presentation 1.0//EN" "xhtml-pres-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-pres-1.mod" "xhtml-pres-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML Qualified Names 1.0//EN" "xhtml-qname-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-qname-1.mod" "xhtml-qname-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Ruby 1.0//EN" "xhtml-ruby-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/ruby/xhtml-ruby-1.mod" "xhtml-ruby-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Scripting 1.0//EN" "xhtml-script-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-script-1.mod" "xhtml-script-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Server-side Image Maps 1.0//EN" "xhtml-ssismap-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-ssismap-1.mod" "xhtml-ssismap-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Document Structure 1.0//EN" "xhtml-struct-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-struct-1.mod" "xhtml-struct-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML Style Sheets 1.0//EN" "xhtml-style-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-style-1.mod" "xhtml-style-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Tables 1.0//EN" "xhtml-table-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-table-1.mod" "xhtml-table-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ELEMENTS XHTML Text 1.0//EN" "xhtml-text-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-text-1.mod" "xhtml-text-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES XHTML 1.1 Document Model 1.0//EN" "xhtml11-model-1.mod"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml11-model-1.mod" "xhtml11-model-1.mod"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES Latin 1 for XHTML//EN" "xhtml-lat1.ent"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent" "xhtml-lat1.ent"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES Special for XHTML//EN" "xhtml-special.ent"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-special.ent" "xhtml-special.ent"
PUBLIC "-//W3C//ENTITIES Symbols for XHTML//EN" "xhtml-symbol.ent"
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-symbol.ent" "xhtml-symbol.ent"
```

Note this is SGML/traditional/plain catalog syntax. If you want to use it with Java/JAXP, you'll have to convert it into a catalog file in XML syntax.